# HTML5 read files from path

Tags: html

Well, using HTML5 file handlining api we can read files with the collaboration of inpty type file. What about ready files with pat like
/images/myimage.png
etc??

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if it is chrome! Play with the filesytem you will be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is; no. When your `HTML/CSS/images/JavaScript` is downloaded to the client's end you are breaking loose of the server.

**Simplistic Flowchart**

- User requests URL in Browser (for example; `www.mydomain.com/index.html`)
- Server reads and fetches the required file (`www.mydomain.com/index.html`)
- index.html and it's linked resources will be downloaded to the user's browser
- The user's Browser will render the HTML page
- - The user's Browser will only fetch the files that came with the request (images/someimages.png and stuff like scripts/jquery.js)

**Explanation**

The problem you are facing here is that when HTML is being rendered locally it has no link with the server anymore, thus requesting what `/images/` contains file-wise is not logically comparable as it resides on the server.

**Work-around**

What you can do, but this will neglect the reason of the question, is to make a server-side script in JSP/PHP/ASP/etc. This script will then traverse through the directory you want. In PHP you can do this by using `opendir()` (http://php.net/opendir).

With a XHR/AJAX call you could request the PHP page to return the directory listing. Easiest way to do this is by using jQuery's `$.post()` function in combination with JSON.

**Caution!**

You need to keep in mind that if you use the work-around you will store a link to be visible for everyone to see what's in your online directory you request (for example `http://www.mydomain.com/my_image_dirlist.php` would then return a stringified list of everything (or less based on certain rules in the server-side script) inside `http://www.mydomain.com/images/`.

**Notes**

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ (seems to work only in Chrome, but would still not be exactly what you want)
- If you don't need all files from a folder, but only those files that have been downloaded to your browser's cache in the URL request; you could try to search online for accessing browser cache (downloaded files) of the currently loaded page. Or make something like a DOM-walker and CSS reader (regex?) to see where all file-relations are.